# Why cant i register a non-regular type Arraylist<> into an ArrayList<>?

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to make a monopoly type game and i am having some issues with with my board. I have made a separate program where i test only the board so i have a Main, a Board and a Square class.
When i am trying to register a square i have issues with my Board class registering the specific square to my Square class. I am providing the code i have for my test program and i have all the imports correct so i need some help with what i have wrong here:

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Board board = new Board();

        board.addSquare("0,Country in conflict.", "Nothing");
        board.getSquare(0);
    }
}
```

And here is my Board class:

```java
public class Board {

    public ArrayList<Square> Squares;

    public void addSquare(String square,String action){
        Square sq = new Square(square, action);
        Squares.add(sq);
    }

    public void getSquare(int square){
        System.out.println(Squares.get(square));
    }
}
```

And here is my Square class:

```java
public class Square{

    public ArrayList<String> actions;
    public final String text;
    public final int squareNumber;

    public Square(String textGiven, String action){
        String textArray[] = textGiven.split(",");
        this.squareNumber = Integer.parseInt(textArray[0]);
        this.text = textArray[1];
        actions.add(action);
    }

    public String getAction(String action){
        return action;
    }

    public int getNumber(){
        return squareNumber;
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    public String toSrting(){
        return squareNumber + ". " + text;
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, the "addSquare" method adds a Square in an uninitialized ArrayList<Square> . Is the program throwing a NullPointerException ? If yes, please initialize your array with new ArrayList<>()

EDIT: and the ArrayList<String> actions is uninitialized too.

Comment: What issues are you ialking anout? Do you get an excepton? Unexpected behaviour? We don´t see your app running, so please provide more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply replace in Board class:

```
public ArrayList<Square> Squares = new ArrayList<Square>();
```

and in Square class (thanks nexevis):

```
public ArrayList<String> actions = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: He has the same issue in his `Square` class too, both would need to be fixed.  Also an explanation of why this fixes it would be good to add.

Answer (score 2):

Your Square class is throwing a `NullPointerException` on your `ArrayList<String> actions` because you havent initialized it yet. You can add this line:

```java
this.actions = new ArrayList<>();
```

to your constructor before accessing it via `.add(...);`

I would also recommend you to change your `Board::addSquare(String, String)` method to `Board::addSquare(Square)` because this keeps Square-logic out of the Board. And if you always know your Squares and their actions, you may change the constructor of your Square class as well. When i began coding i did this too a lot of times but it worked out to be less complex and a more readable code for others.

**EDIT**: Thanks to @Nexevis
Your Board class has the same issue with your `Squares` Arraylist

Comment: His `Board` class also has the same `ArrayList` issue, with the `List` of `Square` too.